# git diff command to exclude certain file types while checking for trailing white space errors

Tags: git, github

I want to check trailing white space errors between two git commits and the following commands works fine for me:

```
git diff ${prev_commit_ID}..${current_commit_ID} --check --relative
```

Please help me to modify this command to exclude some file types such as *.txt, *.pl, *.groovy etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff ${prev_commit_ID}..${current_commit_ID} --check --relative -- . ':!*.txt' ':!*.pl' ':*.groovy'
```

`.` means all the files under the directory.

`:!*.txt` exclude `.txt` files.

Comment: Maybe a little explanation would be useful, if you want to post a complete answer... you could also include a documentation link.